# Help to understand ordered rings and fields examples from Ian Stewart's "The foundations of mathematics"

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, order-theory

Order axioms stated in this book earlier:

[image: Order axioms]

First example:

[image: non-example 10.4]

**Question 1**

I can't get the statement:
$$ \text{Since } 1_n = 1_n \times 1_n = (-1_n)\times(-1_n), \text{ either possibility implies that }1_n ∈ \mathbb{Z}_n^+ \text{ using }(O_1) $$

By ($O_2$) either a($1_n$) or b($-1_n$) ∈ $\mathbb{Z}_n^+$ by definition, but not both.
So what's meant by 'either possibility' and why this magic with $1_n = 1_n \times 1_n = (-1_n)\times(-1_n)$ is needed? What is it for?

**Question 2**

Words: "But this gives the same contradiction as before"
If I get it right, the contradiction was:
$\text{for } 1_n > 0_n, (n-1)_n > 0_n \text{ would then imply } 0_n = 1_n + (n-1)_n > 0_n$, $0_n > 0_n$. 
But this is a logical contradiction, presumed '>' is already defined and works as order relation for $\mathbb{Z}_n$
But where is contradiction in $2_n=1_n+1_n ∈ \mathbb{Z}_n^+,3_n ∈ \mathbb{Z}_n^+, ..., (n-1)_n ∈ \mathbb{Z}_n^+$ ?

Consequences of these examples are used in the next example:
[image: remark]

Sentence:
"As we argued for $\mathbb{Z}_n^+$, we always have 1 > 0 because $1=1^2=(-1)^2$

**Question 3**
How '1 > 0' follows from '$1=1^2=(-1)^2$'?

Comment: "Either possibility" refers to prior phrase: "By (O2) either $1_n \in \mathbb{Z}_n^+$ or $-1_n \in \mathbb{Z}_n^+$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1

He is trying to determine whether $1_n \in \Bbb{Z}_n^+$.

Are you happy that $1_n \times 1_n = 1_n$ and $(-1_n) \times (-1_n) = 1_n$?

If $1_n \in \Bbb{Z}_n^+$ then $1_n \times 1_n = 1_n \in \Bbb{Z}_n^+$ but that is not very exciting.

If $1_n \notin \Bbb{Z}_n^+$ then $-1_n \in \Bbb{Z}_n^+$ so $(-1_n) \times (-1_n) \in \Bbb{Z}_n^+$ but since $(-1_n) \times (-1_n) = 1_n$ this means that $1_n \in \Bbb{Z}_n^+$.

So, as he says, in either case we have proved that $1_n \in \Bbb{Z}_n^+$.

Question 2

The contradiction is that you have proved that $(n-1)_n \in \Bbb{Z}_n$ but $(n-1)_n = -1_n$ and $-1_n$ cannot be in $\Bbb{Z}_n^+$.

Question 3

See my answer to Question 1

Comment: Don't we get a contradiction, when $1_n \notin \mathbb{Z}_n^+$?
As if $1_n \notin \mathbb{Z}_n^+$ then $-1_n \in \mathbb{Z}_n^+$ and by $(-1_n)\times(-1_n)=1_n$ we get that $1_n \in  \mathbb{Z}_n^+$, so both $-1_n \in \mathbb{Z}_n^+$ and $1_n \in \mathbb{Z}_n^+$ which contradicts $(O_2)$.
Or $(O_2)$ states that $1_n$ and $-1_n$ may be in $\mathbb{Z}_n^+$ simultaniously?

Comment: @OleksandrKhryplyvenko Yes, you can view it that way.  Still, it is proved that $1_n \in \Bbb{Z}_n$ which is what we want.